# Adding product to shopping cart not working

Tags: php, mysql

When I click on add to cart, It's not working although the button change from 'Add to cart' to 'Adding' meaning the jquery is working.

I am creating an e-commerce with add to cart functionality but when I click on add to cart the products name is not added to the cart. Although the button changes, meaning the json is working but the selection is not working.

add produce in cart (manage_cart.php)

```
    if(isset($_POST["product_code"])) {
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
            $product[$key] = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        }   
        $statement = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT product_name, product_price FROM products WHERE product_code=? LIMIT 1");
        $statement->bind_param('s', $product['product_code']);
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->bind_result($product_name, $product_price);
        while($statement->fetchAll()){ 
            $product["product_name"] = $product_name;
            $product["product_price"] = $product_price;     
            if(isset($_SESSION["produce"])){ 
                if(isset($_SESSION["produce"][$product['product_code']])) {             
                    $_SESSION["produce"][$product['product_code']]["product_qty"] = $_SESSION["produce"][$product['product_code']]["product_qty"] + $_POST["product_qty"];              
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["produce"][$product['product_code']] = $product;
                }           
            } else {
                $_SESSION["produce"][$product['product_code']] = $product;
            }   
        }   
        $total_product = count($_SESSION["produce"]);
        die(json_encode(array('produce'=>$total_product)));
    }
```

index.php

```
     <?php
            $newstoreobj = $storeobj->select_product();

            if(count($newstoreobj)){
              foreach ($newstoreobj as $data) {
                ?>
                <form class="product-form">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <a href="view_product/product.php?product_id=<?php echo  $data['product_id'] ?>/product<?php echo $data['product_name'].'.html'?>">
                            <div class="prods">
                                <div style="height:250px">
                                    <img src="upload/<?php echo $data['image1'];?>" class="img-responsive" style="padding:20px;height:100%;width:100%" />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p class="text-center" style="color:black; font-weight: bolder;"><?php echo $data['product_name'];?></p>
                                    <p class="text-center" style="color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size:24px">$<?php echo $data['product_price'];?>.00 </p>
                                </div>
                                </a>
                                <select name="product_qty" style="display: none;">
                                <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class="buton" style="width:100;">

                                      <input name="product_code" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data["product_code"];?>"> 
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Add to Cart</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                    </div>
                     </form>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>

    script.js

    // add item to cart
        $(".product-form").submit(function(e){
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();
            var button_content = $(this).find('button[type=submit]');
            button_content.html('Adding...'); 
            $.ajax({
                url: "manage_cart.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType:"json",
                data: form_data
            }).done(function(data){         
                $("#cart-container").html(data.products);
                button_content.html('Add to Cart');             
            })
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

when I click on the add to cart button, I want the product to be added to the cart. Thanks

Comment: That `fetchAll` doesn't look right. Is this a typo?

Comment: I would suggest adding a table holding the cart rather than doing it in session. Then I would do a class for handling cart or stored procedures. The benefit of having cart in db is that you can actually measure conversion (customers who finalize the buy). The benefit of using stored procedures is that you can create wharehouse applications than would be able to use the same code for orders.

Answer (score 0):

One of reason behind this is that you define `die(json_encode(array('produce'=>$total_product)));` in `manage_cart.php`

It means result is stored in `produce` and when you get result in `jquery` using `data.products`.

Thats why its not getting result.

So please replace name in one place either in `manage_cart.php` or `jQuery` code

Comment: So basically I should change the data.products to say data.produce